# Why does my bootstrap drop down menu look unformatted?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning bootstrap for the first time and the dropdown menu seems to be unformatted and doesn't look like the other menu options that I've made. Its also not appearing when clicked, but I followed a tutorial exactly. Any ideas on the problem or mistakes?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Testing</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <nav class='navbar navbar-inverse'>
        <div class='container-fluid'>
            <!--Logo-->
            <div class='navbar-header'>
                <a href="#" class='navbar-brand'>MY LOGO</a>
            </div>

            <!--Menu Items-->
            <div>
                <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
                    <li class='active'><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <!--drop down menu-->
            <li class='dropdown'>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Profile <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>

        </div>
    </nav>

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the `<li class='dropdown'>` within the `<ul class='nav navbar-nav'>`. (The presence of an `<li>` element without a parent list element should probably be cause for alarm in any case.)

So that part of your HTML should be shuffled to look like:

```
<!-- [...] -->

<!--Menu Items-->
<div>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
        <li class='active'><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <!--drop down menu-->
        <li class='dropdown'>
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Profile <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- [...] -->
```

Here's a [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/5VPd3Ttme7) of the revised code. Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks! One other question...Do you know why the dropdown menu does not show when I click on it? For some reason it doesn't work on my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap.min.js needs to come after you load jquery.  I always like to start my documents with the basic template bootstrap shows here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template

It makes it a lot easier to make sure I have everything loading and in the right order.

You will also want to move your dropdown li to be inside your ul with the "nav navbar-nav" class.  Like this:

```
<ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
    <li class='active'><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    <!--drop down menu-->
    <li class='dropdown'>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Profile <span class="caret"></span></a>
         <ul class="dropdown-menu">
             <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
             <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
  </ul>
```